# Jquery, act on external Document

Tags: jquery, jsoup

In Java with jsoup I can do Dom Manipulation like...

```
docInput = Jsoup.parse(new File(this.gp_InputFileName), "utf-8");
Element table = docInput.select("table").get(0);
```

In javascript with Jquery, now I will manipulate docInput with jquery

```
function setOrigAttribute(docInput) { // the extern document: docInput
console.log(docInput);
```

But furtheron how can I act with Jquery on docInput (this holds the complete extern document) instead of "document"?

Or, how can I use the Jquery Library for any String, representing a DOM?

thx so lot

Comment: Jquery is javascript library. It will be difficult to use it in java code. Jsoup has it own methods to manipulate DOM. See for example: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/modifying-data/set-html

Comment: Maybe you should give us the context of your problem. What do you really want to achieve. What you describe here makes not much sense to me. I seems like you are on the wrong track of a problem that is otherwise worth while to explore.